# Disabling Remote-Debugging Connection on Windows 2000

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, remote-debugging

I have two machines one running Win 2000 and one running Win XP both with VSC++ 6.  I created an application using MFC on the Win XP machine (local) and successfully used the Win2000 machine (remote) as the target for debugging.  The code was in a shared drive on the Win2000 machine.  This setup worked well, just like in the movies!

However, I now wish to use my Win2000 machine as a development machine again and I find I can not.  When attempting to execute a natively compiled application on this machine, I get a dialog with the title of "Remote Execution Path And Filename" asking me for same.  When dialog is cancelled as the program that is attempting to execute is not remote, the program terminates without error.

Extra info!
On the WinXP machine, VSC++, under the Build menu->Debugger Remote Connection->Remote Connection Dialog->the "Connection:" list box has two entries 'Local' and 'Network', on the Win2000 machine the 'Local' entry is not present, only the entry for 'Network'.

How do I get back my 'Local' entry on what used to be my target machine (Win2000)?  Will this solve my lack of execution ability from VSC++?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer window and bring up the project's properties.  Under "Configuration Properties" you'll see Debugging.  Change the "Debugger to launch" combo box from "Remote Windows Debugger" to "Local Windows Debugger".

You'll need to do this for any configurations you debug.  If you wish you can set the Configuration combo box to "All Configurations" and change them all at once.